# Из каких стран чаще всего скачивают платные (~1-3$) android приложения?

Tags: android, локализация

Решаю, на какие языки переводить своё приложение. Хотел следовать по [этому списку](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%EF%E8%F1%EE%EA_%FF%E7%FB%EA%EE%E2_%EF%EE_%F7%E8%F1%EB%E5%ED%ED%EE%F1%F2%E8_%E3%EE%E2%EE%F0%FF%F9%E8%F5), но учитывая, что там в топе китайский, арабский, хинди, бенгальский из индии, китая и африки - стран, в которых бедность развита на высшем уровне, следовать этому списку явно не стоит. Так-что помогайте, **где найти top покупающих языков** (понимаю что звучит не по русски, но думаю смысл понятен :) )

Comment: Мне кажется в вопросе кроется ответ...) переводите на языки небедных. Английский - это понятно, далее, французский (заодно и немалую часть Африки захватите), немецкий, испанский. Португальский, японский и корейский из того списка захватить стоит наверно также в первую очередь.

Comment: Из нестандартных - корейский, там очень любят android

Comment: @Kremchik Что-то многовато . Французский, немецкий и английский это обязательно к переводу. А вот испанский, португальский, японский, корейский и итальянский - от этого надо выбирать. Где-нибудь 1 или 2 языка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. USA - 21%
2. Korea - 11%
3. Japan - 6%
4. India - 6%

[Источник](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/appsblog/2012/dec/04/ios-android-revenues-downloads-country)

Но это средняя температура по больнице. Сильно отличается по категориям приложений. Скажем у меня Google Play показывает по категории "Tools", немного другую статистику:

1. USA - 24%
2. Japan - 11%
3. Korea - 10%
4. Germany - 4%
5. Russia - 3%

Но в реальности у меня статистика такая:

1. Russia - 34%
2. USA - 18%
3. Italy - 12%
4. Germany - 5%
5. Netherlands - 3%
6. Korea - 3%

Как я и говорил - сильно зависит от качества перевода, моды, локальных трендов и проч.

Так что думайте сами - решайте сами, переводить или не переводить.

Comment: Спасибо. И всё таки - дайте линк. Это вам не хабрахабр :)

Comment: Линк на что?

Comment: На ваше приложение (которое из tools, статистику которого вы показывали) конечно :-)

Comment: Это противоречит правилам Хэшкод - скрытая реклама.

Comment: @Barmaley да вы издеваетесь?!  Тут некоторые спрашивая почему кнопочка, на их сайте синяя, а не зелёная, дают ссылку на сайт, а вы даже по  просьбе другого участника  линк не хотите выложить...

Comment: Я не некоторые :) Напишите мне в личку скину линк. А правила - есть правила. Если кто-то их нарушает это не повод для остальных.

Comment: В личку куда? В хэше нет лички :).

Comment: бармалей, нарушай пока не модер :)

Answer (score 0):

1. зависит от типа приложения
2. цены
3. магазина в котором размещаешь
4. САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ от его популярности

для начала хватит английского и русского, дальше надо смотреть или на отзывы в сторе или статистику скачиваний по странам

Comment: 1. Инструкции по изготовлению бумажных самолётиков
2. 3$ за полную версию
3. Google play
4. По планам 50 000 - 100 000 загрузок у бесплатной, и 5 000 - 10 000 у платной  
5. 100% будет изначальный перевод на русский, английский и немецкий + 1-2 языка, которые я прошу хэшлюдей выбрать

Comment: то ли дети пошли недоразвитые, то ли я "не в теме"  но зачем для этого целое приложение?

p.s. аж интересно стало что там за самолётики... название (ссылку) на прогу можно?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, насколько я понимаю это что-то типа базы знаний и да, бумажные самолетики бывают разные... Сам лично, в детстве, делал, некоторые, по 5-6 дней.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat приложение включает >30 самолётиков, включая самолёты из Гинеса. Я сам то шестикласник, и в моём классе не все стандартную модель знают, а более 2 моделей знаю только я. Передал друзьям бета версию с 6 моделями. Так они и от них в восторг пришли.  Кстати самолётостроение тяжёлое исскуство. И чём то похоже на программирование - почему не работает и почему не летает

Приложение пока не выложил. Можете посмотреть на  конкурента - bit.ly/107Zi4h .  Правда у него даже в pro версии (покупал) самолёты плохо летают. У меня будет лучше как и по самолётикам, так и по самому приложению :

Comment: @AlexWindHope 5-6 дней это для изготовления объекта самолётик по инструкции в голове или для придумывания инструкции/модели и занесении  её в голову?